# How do I increment the build/version number automatically on TFS Team builds?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I just downloaded the Automatic Versions add-in for VS here (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dd8c5682-58a4-4c13-a0b4-9eadaba919fe/view/Discussions) and it works great locally, but how do I get it to work with Team Builds? Is there something I should install on the build server?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the Automatic Version addin is not called in TFS build even if it is installed on TFS build server machine. In other words, you can't use it to generate incremental assembly version during TFS build process.

Instead, you need to create one custom build process activity to update assembly version, then customize the TFS build process template to add the activity. Please check the following links for the details of the sample build activity and how to customize build process template to use it.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/705482/Updating-Assembly-Versions-During-TFS-Builds 
http://tfssimpleversioning.codeplex.com/
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2010/11/29/incrementing-the-assembly-version-for-each-build-in-tfs-2010.aspx